# Convert string that was originally a `timedelta` back into a `timedelta` object in Python

Tags: python, datetime, serialization, timedelta, elapsedtime

I have strings which were originally produced from `timedelta` objects like so: `print(f'{my_delta}')`.

I have many of these statements logged (e.g. "12:21:00", "1 day, 0:53:00", "2 days, 9:28:00") and I simply want to parse these logged statements to convert back to `timedelta` objects. Is this possible with the `datetime` library?

The strings were literally produced from just printing timedelta objects, but I cannot seem to convert back by using `timedelta(my_string)`. Wondering if there is a standard way of doing this that I am missing.

Comment: "The strings were literally produced from just printing `timedelta` objects, but I cannot seem to convert back by using `timedelta(my_string)`" **there is no reason to believe that you should be able to**. The documentation doesn't seem to state that anywhere. In general, Python only weakly follows the convention that `eval(repr(my_obj))` will typically recreate the original object. But that isn't a guarantee (although, in this case, it would work, but the `repr` might not be what you want to see logged)

Comment: In any case, it sounds like a relatively straightforward regex could be used here.

Comment: Since your data source is serialized logs, it's not very relevant that the log message originated from a `timedelta`. You're really just asking, "how do I parse values out of strings/files/logs?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be amenable to regex, since it seems very regular. It may have days specified at the beginning, or microseconds at the end. But its very... regular:

```py
import re

pattern = r'''
    ((?P<days>-?\d{1,})\ days?,\ )?  # maybe there will be day(s)
    (?P<hours>\d{1,2})  # hours will be one or 2 digits
    :(?P<minutes>\d{2})  # separated by a colon, minutes will be 2 digits
    :(?P<seconds>\d{2})  # separated by a colon, seconds will be 2 digits
    (\.(?P<microseconds>\d{6}))?  # maybe, separated by a period, microseconds will be 6 digits
'''

parse_timedelta_regex = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.VERBOSE)
```

Note, take care using the `re.VERBOSE` flag with spaces, they are ignored outside of specific cases unless you escape them. But I do think it is more readable this way.

Examples of how to use this:

```
>> parse_timedelta_regex.search("1000 days, 0:00:00").groupdict()
{'days': '1000', 'hours': '0', 'minutes': '00', 'seconds': '00', 'microseconds': None}
>>> parse_timedelta_regex.search("1 day, 11:00:13.000130").groupdict()
{'days': '1', 'hours': '11', 'minutes': '00', 'seconds': '13', 'microseconds': '000130'}
```

You could also just write the function to convert the string to timedelta object like so:

```
>>> def string_to_timedelta(s):
...     groups = parse_timedelta_regex.search(s).groupdict()
...     args = {k:int(v) for k,v in groups.items() if v}
...     return datetime.timedelta(**args)
...
>>> string_to_timedelta(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=1337)))
datetime.timedelta(seconds=1337)
```

Here's a more rigorous test (still not very rigorous):

```
>> def test_parse(n):
...     for _ in range(n):
...         seconds = random.random()*100_000_000
...         td = datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)
...         parsed = string_to_timedelta(str(td))
...         assert td == parsed
...
>>> test_parse(1000)
>>> test_parse(10_000)
>>> test_parse(100_000)
```

Comment: Is the `?P<>` syntax utilized by `groupdict` python-specific? i.e. using such a regex in a different language or from the general regex spec would result in literally matching these characters?

Comment: @efthimio the feature is called a "named capture group". Not sure if the syntax is common, but it is a feature of other regex engines, see: https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted emphatically, the `datetime` library does not seem to support this functionality.

Here's a one-liner that uses regex:

```py
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> str_to_dlt = lambda t: timedelta(days=int((m:=re.match(r'((\d+)\sdays?,\s*)?(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})', t))[2] or 0), hours=int(m[3]), minutes=int(m[4]), seconds=int(m[5]))
```

Printing the timedelta returns the original string it was supplied:

```py
>>> print(str_to_dlt('5:11:13'))
5:11:13
>>> 
>>> print(str_to_dlt('1 day, 5:11:13'))
1 day, 5:11:13
>>> 
>>> print(str_to_dlt('2 days, 5:11:13'))
2 days, 5:11:13
```